# adding alternating values to a string with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe, in the ID column the values are strings: `1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5, etc...`.

I would like to add to the string so it looks like `1.1,1.2,2.1,2.2,3.1,3.2, etc...`

Ideally, if there is a third or fourth identical value then it is logically updated like `1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4, etc...`

How is this best achieved?

Answer (score 3):

You'd have to use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html). Then use concatenate them using [`Series.str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html).

```
# s = pd.Series(['1', '1', '2', '2', '3', '3', '4', '4', '5', '5'])
s.str.cat(s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).astype(str), sep='.')

# 0    1.1
# 1    1.2
# 2    2.1
# 3    2.2
# 4    3.1
# 5    3.2
# 6    4.1
# 7    4.2
# 8    5.1
# 9    5.2
# dtype: object
```

Comment: what if it has to start from '.0' instead of '.1'?

Comment: remove the `.add(1)` to start from 0. You can use `.add` to give any offset you need.